# Panda Dataframe Select Filter And Aggregate in 1 statement

Tags: python, pandas

How can I do a select, filter and agg all in one statement...(pieces below)

```
df = df.loc[df['Gender'] == ('M'),['Name','Gender','Weight']]
df = df.groupby(['Name','Gender']).agg({'Weight': np.sum})
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag this "pandas" as well?

Comment: Yes, that applies as well

Comment: If you are already selecting a particular gender, why are you grouping by gender?

Comment: You can chain the `.` operation to a `DataFrame`. Like  `df.loc[df['Gender'] == ('M'),['Name','Gender','Weight']].groupby(['Name','Gender']).agg({'Weight': np.sum})`

Comment: df.loc[df['Gender'] == ('M'),['Name','Gender','Weight']].groupby(['Name','Gender'].agg({'Weight': np.sum})
                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':np.random.choice(['M','F'],size=10),
                   'Name':np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),10),
                   'Weight':np.random.randint(50,250,10),
                   'Height':np.random.randint(3,15,10)})

print(df)
```

Output df

```
  Gender  Height Name  Weight
0      M       5    A     153
1      M      10    A     103
2      M       5    C     185
3      F       4    B      82
4      M       4    C     112
5      M      12    B     224
6      M      12    D     131
7      F       6    D     193
8      F      12    B      78
9      F      13    C      58
```

Do filter and group one statement:

```
df.loc[df['Gender']=='M',['Name','Gender','Weight']].groupby(['Name','Gender']).agg({'Weight':'sum'})

             Weight
Name Gender        
A    M          256
B    M          224
C    M          297
D    M          131
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. install pandasql

sudo pip install -U pandasql

### 2. run sample code

```
from random import sample, random
from string import uppercase, lowercase
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

l = lambda x: {'u': sample(uppercase, 1)[0], 'l': sample(lowercase, 1)[0], 'r': random()}
df = DataFrame(map(l, range(10000)))
result = pysqldf(''' select l, sum(r) sr from df where l in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') group by l ''')
result
```